# How to rm function multiple patterns

Tags: r, regex

I am just wondering how I may be able to shorten the following code, just for better practice:

```
rm(list=ls(pattern="^DC"))
rm(list=ls(pattern="^HX"))
rm(list=ls(pattern="^Time"))
rm(list=ls(pattern="^Code"))
```

There must be a way to make this code more concise.

Comment: Maybe use OR `|` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(DC|HX|Time|Code)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/IRWtqG/1).

Also, see [Alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and [Grouping and Capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) reference.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - an alternation capturing group (you may use `(?:` to start a non-capturing one)

  - `DC` - `DC` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `HX` - a `HX` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `Time` - a `Time` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `Code` - a `Code` substring
- `)` - end of the grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Use `|` (or) in the regex.

```
DCA <- 1
HX1 <- 2
Time <- 3
Code <- 4
x <- 5
ls(pattern="(^DC)|(^HX)|(^Time)|(^Code)")
#[1] "Code" "DCA"  "HX1"  "Time"
```